# split hours in a day and perform some login for each hour in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

how can I split hours in a day and perform some logic for each hour in a day in powershell.

the below program is the one which gets the avg, min and max values of data in a text file in a  given day . now I need to get the same values hourly . ie i need avg max and min values hourly ie 24 times an output to a file

$servers = @("server1","server2","server3","server4","server5","server5","server6","sever7")

```
    $tgtDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd

    $dstFile = "C:\scripts\test.txt"



    # create the output file

    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $dstFile -Force

    #

    foreach ($server in $servers)

    {      

        $tgtFolder = "\\$server\LogFiles\foo_pilot\"

        Write-Verbose "Target date $tgtDate on $server"

        $serverData = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $tgtFolder -ChildPath "foo.log$tgtDate") |

        select-string 'Elapsed time for PICKLIST_SERVICEv10.getFilWorkLoad:' -SimpleMatch|

        out-file $dstFile -Append

    }

   $max = $avg = $totalTime = 0.0

   $min = 100.0 # set this to something greater than the largest time

   $count = 0

   $data = Get-Content $dstFile 

   $pattern = "(?'min'\d{2}):(?'sec'\d{2})\.(?'hun'\d{2})"

   foreach ($item in $data)

        {

           if ($item -match $pattern)

            {

                # bump the count for the average

                $count++

                # convert mm:ss.dd to seconds

                $time = $Matches.hun / 100 + [int]$Matches.min * 60 + $Matches.sec

                # keep track of the total time for the average

                $totalTime += $time

                # update the max and min

                $max = [Math]::Max($max,$time)

                $min = [Math]::Min($min,$time)

            }

        }

   # calculate the average

   $avg = $totalTime / $count

   # write the output

   $max | Out-File -FilePath $dstFile -Append

   $min | Out-File -FilePath $dstFile -Append

   $avg | Out-File -FilePath $dstFile -Append
```

Comment: Why not use the Windows Scheduler to perform the timing for your script?

Comment: it could help if you can provide some of the $dstFile content

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the current hour, then it's pretty simple to get the hour using .NET.

```
$myVariable = [DateTime]::Now
$myVariable.Hour # returns the hour from the DT object
```

Just the current hour by itself is easy, too:

```
[DateTime]::Now.Hour # returns just the int hour
```

If all you need to do is convert the times in your strings, there's a simple way to do that, too:

```
[DateTime]::Parse($inputString) # variable named $time in your code
```

Once you've got your time strings in date/time format, it's pretty easy to perform operations from there. If you need to perform an operation based on a given hour, then you can do something like a foreach construct through your collection of time strings. Keep in mind that this will natively be in 24/hr format, so 6:00 PM is 18.

An example of storing the hours the way you said you need to would be below:

```
# regex to get the time string
$variable = [DateTime]::Parse($time)
$totalTime += $variable.Hour
```

Then, you can continue performing your operations from there as is. Keep in mind that using Parse assumes that your data is in the correct format each time. If the regex works, each time, then you're set as is, but I like to add error handling even when I don't expect there to be an error. One way you could mitigate errors here would be putting the conversion in a Try block, and catching the exceptions, then incrementing an exception variable. See below:

```
$parseExceptions = 0
try
{
    [DateTime]::Parse($string)
}
catch
{
    ++$parseExceptions
}
```